# Yahoo returns different identity URL when using OpenID with delegation

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

I'm implementing an OpenID based login system with [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid). Following the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/wiki/Configuration#wikimaincol), I use the `$openid->identity` property to set and get the identity supplied by the user:

> Set it before calling authUrl(), and get after validate().

So I do as follows:

```
<?php

$openid = new OpenID;

if( !$openid->mode ){
    if( isset($_POST['openid']) ){
        // Auth required
        $openid->identity = $_POST['openid'];
        header('Location: ' . $this->authUrl());
        exit;
    }

}elseif( $openid->mode == 'cancel' ){
    // Cancelled by user

}else{
    if( $this->validate() ){
        // Sucess
        $user = $openid->identity;
    }else{
        // Error
    }
}
```

When I test the system with *delegation* (I believe that's the technical name: I type my domain name in the login box and get authenticated with a third-party provider) the resulting identity is not always the one I initially typed and this behaviour seems to depend on the provider behind the scenes. More specifically, if I type `http://example.com/` Yahoo will always return `https://me.yahoo.com/XXXXXXXXXX#5ab6d` where `XXXXXXXXXX` is my Yahoo username. As a result, I can't reliably identify recurring users: as soon as they switch providers, they'll lose their account data in my site:

```
["openid_claimed_id"] => string(37) "https://me.yahoo.com/XXXXXXXXXX#5ab6d"
["openid_identity"] => string(31) "https://me.yahoo.com/XXXXXXXXXX"
```

My questions:

- Is this behaviour correct?
- Is my code wrong?

*(Please correct me if I'm misusing any term. Everything around OpenID tends to overcomplication, esp. the terminology.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know it isn't correct behavior on the part of the provider.

Yahoo (and AOL, by the way) just does that. The only way to fix this is to start using a different provider.

As for your second question, your code is correct. Remember though, that the authentication status isn't remembered automatically, and you have to store it in a session yourself (if you want it to persist between requests, of course).

Comment: Oh my... I wonder if there's a single OpenID provider out there that actually works :( Thank you for the tip. BTW, the rest of my code is basically finished; I'm only stuck in these sort of OpenID subtleties.